# How do I add a component after an submit event using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a component after a submit event from another component.

```js
var Extention  = React.createClass({
render: function(){ 
   alert("Enters the function");
    return(
        <div id="fitnesse-panel"> 
            this is where my second form code is located
        </div> 
        );
}
 });

var FormButton = React.createClass({ 
handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return (<Extention/>);
},
render: function() {
    return (
                <form role="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="submit" value ="" />
                </form> 
            );
}
});
```

What I am trying to do is click the submit button in `<Formbutton/>` to load `<Extention/>` on to the page. The `Extension` component renders the function but the JSX is not returned to the browser. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var FormButton = React.createClass({ 
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {'submitted': false};
    },

    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({'submitted': true });
    },
    render: function() {
        if (this.state.submitted) {
            return <Extention/>;
        }
        else {
            return (
                <form role="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="submit" value ="" />
                </form> 
            );
        }
    }
});
```